# How to place dialog box code in some place and call it from all views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-dialog

So how to place jquery dialog box code in a specific file and call it from multiple views. Right now I am placing the dialog box code in all the views where ever I required to do so. I want to know is there any way to call it like how we reference styles and jquery files. If so then please explain with an example will be appreciated. Can @Scripts.Render(" ") has to do anything here.

Comment: you can better create a wrapper js and add the reference in all views

Comment: Create a normal js file push the common code to it and include that js file in your layout so it will be available accross all the pages sharing that layout.

Answer (score 0):

If the dialog box code is just JS. Then add the code to a java script file, and add your file to the _layout. (If you know about bundles, you can also add the file to a bundle - if you don't its okay)

if the code also require some HTML then also add the HTML to your _layout, or create it as a partial view and use the render partial view method in places that you need it.